# EF persists columns I don't want it to, how to avoid this behaviour?

Tags: entity-framework, enums, mapping

From the code sample of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076940/should-the-enumdatatypeattribute-work-correctly-in-net-4-0-using-entity-framewo), I added a string property to my wrapper, and then I only want it for GUI and tests purposes, I don't want this string property to be persisted into the database. The wrapper looks the same as sampled in the linked question with this add-on:

```
public string StringValue {
    get {
        return stringValues[Value];
    }
    set {
        if (stringValues.Contains(value))
            t = (StreetType)stringValues.Single(s => s == value).IndexOf(value);
    }
}

public static implicit operator string(StreetTypeWrapper w) {
    return w == null ? stringValues[0] : w.StringValue;
}

public static implicit operator StreetTypeWrapper(string s) {
    return new StreetTypeWrapper() { StringValue = s };
}
```

Not to mention that I never changed the `StreetTypeMapping` complex type mapping class to include this new property, I don't want it in the database, but EF keeps persisting it anyway, though I only mapped the `Value` property of this complex type.

**Is there something I do wrong for this to happen?**

**How can I avoid this annoying behaviour?**
(EF decides for me what to map though I specified what to map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to the property

```
[NotMapped]
public string StringValue { .... }
```

if there is some way to make the property read-only, then EF will ignnore it also.

Comment: +1 I managed to make the property read-only, and thanks for the information. The answer is so simple that I feel almost shy to have asked. ;)